# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in my code

Tags: laravel

I am facing this error when I tried to redirect my page from main dashboard to the view profile page. I'm using Laravel 5.8 and below is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{Route::redirect('/admin.dashboard', '/view profile')}}">View profile</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Setting</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your route makes no sense. What are you trying to do? Where do you want your `href` to go? `Route::redirect()` is not the correct thing to use there, should be `url()` or `route()`, but I'm not sure where you want to go.

Comment: i want to redirect to view profile page when user click on it

Comment: Route::get('/view profile', function () {
    return view('view profile');
});
here is my route

Comment: `Route::get('/view profile', ...);` is not valid... You can't have spaces in a URL. `Route::get('/view-profile`, ...);` is valid, in which case you'd use `{{ url('/view-profile') }}`

Answer (score 4):

In your web.php file define a route like this:

```
Route::get('/view-profile', function () { return view('view profile'); });
```

and then in your link just use this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/view-profile')}}">View profile</a>
```

Comment: The above question does not require redirection at all. He is already on current dashboard and just need a href="/view-profile" to go to instead.
Your code will not let him open dashboard at all.